# Selector image change with background on press

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview, selector

I have a background set in my activity_main.xml simply as that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background4">
```

And I also have this imageview:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:src="@drawable/contact" />
```

and my selector.xml looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/contact_pressed"/>
  <item 
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/contact"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/contact"/>
</selector>
```

And nothing happens on image press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:src="@drawable/contact" />
```

with this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:src="@drawable/selector" />
```

Obviously your `selector.xml` should be into `drawable` folder

Comment: mmh, ok. what logcat says?

Comment: Ohh now it works... have no idea what happened last time... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The selector you mention above IS a background. What View are you trying to use? Maybe use an ImageView, you can set your selector as the "background" then use the image as the "src"? Alternatively, you could use seperate overlapping views in a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout